# phpDoc, class instance as @param?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

When using phpdoc on a function I have an argument that always contains an instance of a class, is there any way to document this in phpdoc so that the generated phpdoc links to the given class?

Something like `@param MyClass() $var`.

I can't find any info on it in the documentation, in fact the documentation doesn't even mention objects (stdClass) type params, period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the parenthesis and it should work out of the box:

```
@param MyClass $var Parameter takes instance of MyClass
```

The formal syntax for this is:

```
@param type [$varname] description
```

Have a look at the documentation http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/ (you need to click on @param on the left)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Ironic that developers that create software used for documenting code don't document their code very well.. :)

Comment: Actually, they do: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/ and click on @param